# Jmeter is not extracting correctly the value with the reg ex extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter

Jmeter is not extracting correctly the value with the regex.
When I play with this regex `(NAME="token" \s value="([^"]+?)")` in regex coach with the following html everything work fine but when adding the reg with a regex extrator to the request he doesn't found the value even if it's the same html in output.

```
<HTML>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dostuff(no, applicationID)
    {
        submitAction('APPS_NAME' , 'noSelected=' + no + '&applicationID=' + applicationID);
    }
</script>

<FORM NAME="baseForm" ACTION="" METHOD="POST">
    <input type="hidden" NAME="token" value="fc95985af8aa5143a7b1d4fda6759a74" >

<div id="loader" align="center">
        <div>
            <strong style="color: #003366;">Loading...</strong>
        </div>
        <img src="images/initial-loader.gif" align="top"/>
    </div>

<BODY ONLOAD="dostuff('69489','test');">

</FORM>
</HTML>
```

**From the Regular Expression Extractor**

```
Reference Name: token
Regular Expression: (NAME="token" \s value="([^"]+?)")
Template: $1$
Match No.: 1
Default value: wrong-token
```

The request following my the POST of the previous code is returning:

```
POST data:
token=wrong-token
```

in the next request in the tree viewer.

But when I check a the real request in a proxy the token is there.

Note: I tried the regex without the bracket and doesn't worked either.

Do anybody have a idea whats wrong here?
Why jmeter can't find my token with the regex extrator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex looks for the text `NAME="token"`, followed by a space, followed by a space, tab or newline, followed by a space, followed by the text `value="`, followed by one or more non-quote characters, followed by another `"`.

If it doesn't find that in the string it's looking at (and your text sample doesn't match), it fails.

What are you really trying to do? It looks like you're parsing HTML with regex. Not a good idea.

Comment: I'm trying to extract the value of the token to a jmeter variable so that the next request will be able to have the value. 
More info on that here http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

I'm trying to get the value after value= between quote.

Comment: Thanks for your input Tim it helped me to find out what was the problem. 
It's seem that reg ex coach ignore the space in my reg ex but not jmeter. I found a tool on the jakarta-oro site (http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/demo.html) that use the same matching pattern and I was able to found a reg ex that work. The actual reg ex that work is (NAME="token".value="([^"]+?)")

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly use [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead of Regular Expression Extractor.

Your xpath query should return value you want to extract.
In this case it will look like:

```
//input[@type="hidden"][@name="token"]/@value
```

Extracted value will be stored in jmeter variable pointed in 'Reference Name' field of XPath Extractor (e.g. `${token}` in your case).

**NOTE:** Since here XPath Extractor is used to parse HTML (not XML) response ensure that **Use Tidy (tolerant parser)** option is CHECKED (in [XPath Extractor's control panel](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the regex formats as follows:

```
Reference Name: token
Regular Expression: NAME="token"\svalue="(.+)"
Template: $1$
Match No.: 1
Default value: wrong-token
```