# Regular Expression Extractor doesn't capture given regex

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have this set-up in Jmeter as follows

```
TestPlan
    GetToken
        HTTP Request
            Regular Expression Extractor

            ReferenceName     : token
            Regular Expression: "Token": "(.+?)"
            Template          : $1$
            Match No.         : 1
            Default Value     : NO_TOKEN_VALUE


        Debug Sampler
        View Results Tree
```

When I run my test, I can see the result in `View Results Tree`. When I test my regex in `RegExp Tester`, it returns:

```
Match count: 1
Match[1][0]="Token": "1234567890"
Match[1][1]=`1234567890
```

However, when I view the `Debug Sampler`, I always get:

```
token=NO_TOKEN_VALUE
```

Does anybody know what might be causing this?

Comment: have you changed the `Apply To:` or `Response field to check:` fields in the Regex Extractor config?

Comment: Check below please :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811330/jmeter-is-not-extracting-correctly-the-value-with-the-reg-ex-extractor

Comment: @CharlieS `Apply to:` is set to `Main sample and sub-samples` and `Response Field to check` is set to `Response Message`

Comment: @CharlieS You were correct, I should have checked `body` instead of `Response Message`. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct settings for the fields in Regex Extractor config:

`Apply To: Main Sample and Sub-samples`

`Response Field To Check: Body`